# Is there such set?

Tags: cardinals

Is there a set $A\ \subseteq P(\{x_1, x_2,  x_3, \ldots \}) $ of cardinality $\aleph$ such that for every two sets $B,C\in A$: $B\ \cap C=B $ or $B\ \cap C=C  $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\{\{x_1\},\{x_1, x_2\}, \{x_1, x_2, x_3\}, \ldots \} $

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [**ordinals**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number). An ordinal is a hereditarily transitive set - that is, $\alpha$ is an ordinal if

- Whenever $x\in y\in\alpha$, we also have $x\in\alpha$ (*$\alpha$ is transitive*); and
- Whenever $z\in\alpha$, and $x\in y\in z$, then $x\in z$ (*ever element of $\alpha$ is transitive*).

*(There are other equivalent definitions, but I find this one the easiest to think about.)* Some examples of ordinals are:

- $\emptyset$ is (trivially) an ordinal.
- $\{\emptyset\}$ is also an ordinal.
- If $\alpha$ is an ordinal, then so is $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$.
- And if $\alpha_i$ ($i\in I$) are all ordinals, then their *union* is also an ordinal.

It's a good exercise to show that every element of an ordinal is an ordinal. Additionally, it turns out that the ordinals are linearly ordered (in fact, [well-ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order)) by $\in$; these two facts imply that given any two ordinals $\alpha,\beta$, either $\alpha\subseteq\beta$ or $\beta\subseteq \alpha$. So since there are [arbitrarily large ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number), this gives you the result you're looking for, regardless of what cardinality you're looking for.

---

Another good example is provided by *linear orders* in general - like $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Let's look at $\mathbb{Q}$ to be concrete. For $q\in \mathbb{Q}$, let $$A_q=\{p\in\mathbb{Q}: p<q\}.$$ Then what can you say about $A_{q_1}\cap A_{q_2}$ for $q_1\le q_2$?

Comment: Actually the last example also works with $q\in\Bbb R$, i.e., we have an uncountable family of countable sets with the desired property.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Indeed, I didn't mean to imply that it only worked for $\mathbb{Q}$.